# Term position of a query terms in solr results

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-schema, solr-search

I am trying to find the position of query terms in result documents.

For that I am using **'/tvrh'** RequestHandler with **tv.positions=true**.

However I am receiving positions for all the terms in a doc, but I only need the position of query terms.

I am attaching a screenshot of a sample example.
Here, I am searching on *Content* field and trying to find a way to get positions of only query terms (whereas **tv.positions=true** returns position for all terms).

Here I only need positions of **to** and **girl**.

It would be great, if this could be solved at Solr end.

[image]